# How to set ajax returned value as a variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call which executes successfully:

```
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
   {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );

            var memberid = 'memberid='+ aData[6];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "shout.php",
                data: memberid,
                success: function(html) {
                    //$("#shout").html(html);   
                    var sOut = html.returned_val;
                }
            });

            return sOut;
        }
```

If I remove the commented out line ($("shout").html(html) and use a div on my page, the results display fine. However, there is a second function which would use the HTML results from sOut and display accordingly in the proper position.

The PHP file in shout.php simply 'echos' HTML to the page (which is then returned and displayed accordingly.

I am unfortunately unable to set the variable sOut currently based on the results of my ajax call. What am I missing?

Comment: not sure why my question was downvoted? the appropriate member who did so could at least have the courtesy to explain

Comment: are you sure that it actually hits php server and gives proper response?

Comment: @fazo - yes. if it did not, the return variable with the (currently) commented would not populate correctly. $("#shout") represents a div which populates based on the html returned from the php script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like your function to return what returns from the AJAX call, you need to make the call synchronously.  Also, this is assuming the result of "shout.php" is plaintext.  If it's JSON or otherwise, you need to set the `dataType` property in your call to `$.ajax`.

```
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr ) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var memberid = 'memberid='+ aData[6];

    var result;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "shout.php",
        data: memberid,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. For some reason - the result keeps returning 'undefined'. if I uncomment the hidden div portion, the number returns so i atleast know the call it working properly

Comment: any thoughts? I've tried it just about every which way and no go.

Comment: @JM4 - I'm an idiot, I originally wrote `async: true` here, when I should have written `async: false`.  I fixed my answer.  Try changing that in your code.

Comment: Same issue and your solution works well !!,   I like your confession as well.

Comment: Works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are defining sOut within a success callback method and therefore it would not be available to fnFormatDetails.

Secondly by default $.ajax works in async mode, therefore whenever "return sOut" is called, the success callback would have not executed !

I would suggest you to call some method from the success which would do the process based on the html.returned_val, or you can pass async:false in $.ajax to make that call synchronized.

Comment: your logic in the second paragraph makes sense though passing async:false into the ajax call does not solve the issue. I am not sure why the success callback method could not have details used within the function itself honestly. Perhaps I do not have a full understanding but the commented code if uncommented is able to display content with the specified "shout" div if any call is made

Answer (score 1):

thank you  @Matt Huggins

**async: false**

this small code change, fixed the issue i was having since morning.  :)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks a lot!